# Python Round decimal to next decimal and not closest decimal?

Tags: python

Let's say X = 1.14
And I want to round X up to 1.20 and not 1.10
How do I do this?

I have tried...

```
print(round(x,2))
```

and the output is 1.10

Comment: If you are actually asking about rounding of decimals rather than floats then this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import math

x = 1.14
rounded_up = math.ceil(x * 10) / 10  # round up to one decimal place
print(rounded_up)
```